# How would I go about finding how many combinations based on this criteria.

Tags: combinatorics

Alright, say I have a 30 letter string.

- I can put `.` or `+` between any two letters
- There can be any amount of `.` and `+` in a "modified string"
- I cannot put  `.` or `+` before the first letter or after the last letter
- I cannot put `.` next to `.`, `+` next to `+` or `.` next to `+`, in any order.

Comment: What have you tried?  Though I am not sure the rules are clear.  What is the answer if you start with a $2$ letter string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that there are no `.` or `+` in the original string:

$3^{29} = 68630377364883$.

Each consecutive pair of letters will either have a `.`, a `+`, or neither in between them.  These choices are independent, i.e. your choice for the first pair of letters does not effect what choices are available for the second.  There are three choices for each pair (`.`, `+`, or nothing) and 29 pairs, so you just multiply each independent choice: $3\cdot3\cdot3...=3^{29} = 68630377364883$

Comment: Are you sure it's not 29^3? That number seems incredibly high.